# Joining a list of lists together when generated from a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm batch importing some summary files for analysis

```
SummaryFileList = FileNames["*.csv*"];
AllSummaryFiles = 
Table[
        SummaryFile = 
        Import[SummaryFileList [[i]]],
        {i, 1, NumberOfSummaryFiles}
     ]
```

Which will produce

```
{AllSummaryFiles[[1]], AllSummaryFiles[[2]],...,AllSummaryFiles [[i]] }
```

I'd like to join the output of these tables, at the moment the only way to achieve the desired result is to manualy choose each element of the list of lists as:

```
Join[AllSummaryFiles[[1]], AllSummaryFiles[[2]],AllSummaryFiles[[3]]]
```

The problem is obviously the outer brackets of the table output is there a way to acheive the above result without manually picking out the induvidual list.

---

Essentially, if I import all my summary files sequentially I want to join them all together so that they form a big long list in the order in which they were imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
Join @@ Import["*.csv"]
```

also, are you sure you want the * after csv?

Some explanation of the code above:

```
Import["*.csv"]
```

imports all the files above as a list: if you have three .csv files (1.csv,2.csv,3.csv), the output will be

> {file_data1,file_data2,file_data3}

This would be equivalent of your code:

```
SummaryFileList = FileNames["*.csv"];
NumberOfSummaryFiles = Length[SummaryFileList];
AllSummaryFiles = Table[
   Import[SummaryFileList [[i]]],
   {i, 1, NumberOfSummaryFiles}
]
```

which, however, would read better as:

```
SummaryFileList = FileNames["*.csv"];
AllSummaryFiles = Table[
   Import[i],
   {i, 1, SummaryFileList}
]
```

In both cases, the Table loop is redundant as Import deals with many files automatically, hence one should use just Import["*.csv"]

You then want to Join your files: the way to do it is:

```
Join @@ AllSummaryFiles
```

which replicates you example:

```
Join[AllSummaryFiles[[1]], AllSummaryFiles[[2]],AllSummaryFiles[[3]]]
```

for a generic length of the list AllSummaryFiles

As obvious, it's much more convenient (and also efficient) to type only Join @@ Import["*.csv"] rather than the whole Table loop, unless you have a specific reason for doing so.

Comment: Your solution just replicates my problem with joining the output of the table I'm afraid. The second `*` doesn't seem to make a difference for my particular case.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data files (a couple of them should be enough), and elaborate on what your problem is? Maybe it's just me, but I don't get what's the problem you need to solve :)

Comment: Regarding the * after csv, it means that if you have files with an extension that is csv+something else then you will import those as well, while if you use only *.csv you are importing the csv files only

Comment: @Q.P. You could use `MapIndexed[Export["File" <> ToString[First[#2]] <> ".csv", #1] &, 
 Table[{i, j}, {i, 5}, {j, 5}]]` to generate a minimal working example. Do you want to join only a subset of list elements? Like `Join @@ AllSummaryFiles[[{1, 2, 3}]]`?

Comment: I essentially want to import all my CSV files and attach them as a big long list in the order they were imported

Comment: Isn't what the code I posted does? Can you explain what is the problem with it so I can amend it?

Comment: @JoshBishop generating the files is not the problem, the problem is that it's not clear what the OP needs to achieve, and having a couple of files and an explanation of where his code breaks would be helpful to fix the issue :)

Comment: The problem is that your code is functionally the same as `Join[{File1, File2, File3}]` however the outer set of `{}`mess up the list formatting so you end up with some oddly transposed object, which can't be transposed especially if the files are of different lengths. The only way I can achieve the desired outcome is to basically go `Join[File1,File2,File3]` Note there is no enclosing `{}`. I guess fundamentally the problem is removing the outer `{}` of a list while keeping them around the  elements. Remember that the elements for me are whole CSV files. I hope this is clearer?

Comment: To be honest, it's still not clear to me (but it has been a long day, so I might just being stupid :D ). I still think that providing an example of the .csv files (they don't have to be the original ones, you could just create two ad hoc as example) and how your code breaks would be helpful to us, so we could help you! But again, maybe it's just me and someone else has understood what you need to achieve!

Comment: Also, I don't think that what you say is true: my code is not functionally the same as Join[{File1, File2, File3}], while it's actually doing Join[File1,File2,File3]: this is because I'm using Apply (@@): for example, f @@ {a, b, c, d} corresponds to f[a, b, c, d], if you replace f with Join it's exactly what (as far as I understand) you are asking.

Comment: Could you provide an example including the Table loop? Maybe I misunderstood your intial answer, I essentially added your answer insider my loop where I import and It didn't like it!

Comment: That's not what I meant with my code! You should use my code INSTEAD of your code and it should do what you are asking for. Try it, while I amend my answer implementing a Table version of it (even if it's much more verbose)

Comment: I'm afraid it was me who was being stupid!